# Is there a shorthand function for this repetitive equation

Tags: exponentiation

I was looking for a way to get the answer to this equation without having to repeatedly type out each number
$$
x^{y}+x^{y+1}+x^{y+2}+...+x^{y+n}
$$
What is the smallest equation that outputs the same answer as this one?

Comment: This is not an equation.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n x^{y+i}$ maybe?

Comment: xʸ+xʸ⁺¹+xʸ⁺²+...+xʸ⁺ⁿ=z

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. Check out math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to get started if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: $$
x^{y}+x^{y+1}+x^{y+2}+...+x^{y+n}=z
$$

Comment: $x^y(1+x+\cdots+x^n)=x^y(1-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$

Answer (score 0):

The smallest shorthand is $S$.

If you need to express this sum for other variables and/or other numbers of terms, you need to add them as argument or indexes.

E.g. $S_w$ with meaning $\displaystyle\sum_{k=y}^{y+n}w^k$.